# How to show that the given set $\{x \in X \,|\, d_A(x) < \varepsilon\}$ is open?

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Let $A$ be a subset in a metric space $(X, d).$ Show that the set $\{x \in X \,|\, d_A(x) < \varepsilon\}$ is open for any $\varepsilon  > 0$  by using the continuity of $d_A.$

My question is $d_A(x)$ can be $0$ since $x \in A \subset X$ then $d_A^{-1}([0, \varepsilon)) = [0, \varepsilon),$ but this set is not open. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure what $f$ is in this context. I am also confused as to why $d_A$ does not take two inputs.

Comment: By the way, the inverse image of an open set under a continuous function is an open set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that $d_A(x)$ is the distance of a point $x \in X$ from the subset $A$. Note $d_A$ maps $X$ onto $[0,\infty)$ and the subset $[0,\epsilon)$ is open in $[0,\infty)$(in the subspace topology induced by $\Bbb R$). If you assume the continuity of $d_A$, then $d_A^{-1}([0,\epsilon))$ is an open set in $X$.

Comment: It is open by the very definition of the subspace topology. If you do not understand this, I suggest you read up on the subspace topology before proceeding further.

Comment: $U \subset \mathbb{R}_+$ is open in $\mathbb{R}_+$ if, by definition of the induced topology, there exists an open subset $V \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $U = V\cap \mathbb{R}_+$. Here, take $V = (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$.

Answer (score 1):

The map

$$d_A: A \times A \to [0,\infty[$$

has codomain $[0, \infty[$.

Here, $[0,\infty[$ has the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$. This means that a subset $A$ of $[0,\infty[$ is open if we can write it as $A= [0,\infty[ \cap G$ where $G$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Thus, $$[0,\epsilon[ = [0, \infty[\cap]-\epsilon, \epsilon[$$
is open in $[0,\infty[$.

Comment: Thank you now i understand what is going on.

Comment: You are very welcome!